# promotion during appraisal or midyear

Tags: promotion

I am entitled to be a Manager when I was given an interview as the position was for manager, when offer was made to me it was Deputy Manager.

I had to accept as this was also a good one and shared my views on that its not right on their part and they confirmed they will look into it in next appraisal

Now we are in October, please suggest if its good to check and get the tag of manager now or in March/April

I am afraid in March/April they all will be busy only on annual appraisal than promotion and may lead to wait for another few months or a year for me.

Comment: This is nothing we can answer here. You have to decide yourself what is best for your career.

Comment: Do you expect us to know without you telling us when the next performance appraisal is supposed to be? Why don't you be clear AT WHAT MONTH did they interview you and tell you that they would look at your promised promotion and AT WHAT MONTH that performance appraisal was supposed to be?